# flat file parsing in shell

Tags: parsing, shell, unix, awk, fixed

I have a fixed length file of the format :

```
Name       Age        Party              Role 
---------- ---------- ------------------ --------------
Shubham    27         XYZ                User
Drek       28         ABC                Admin
Raj        23         USR                User
```

Now I want to write a shell script/command to output a file containing all Parties with Age<25
In this case, it should print something like this :

```
Party
-----------------
USR
```

I am new to awk and shell. I tried using awk, and substr but it is way too expensive since my file is huge (>200000 lines with multiple columns). Is there a neat way to do this ?

**Update**

Any of the fields can have spaces within them. The real idea is that the file is a fixed length file. So length of each record is fixed (Name:10, Age:10, Part:20,Role:10). The Records however can have anything in the dat including spaces and blanks. For instance:

```
Name       Age        Party              Role 
---------- ---------- ------------------ --------------
Shub A     27         XYZ & A            User
Drek GH    28         ABC & C            Admin
Raj        23         USR                User
```

and so on. 
Now I want to use Name to do a select, such that my script prints Party records where Name = "Shub A" . So here output should be :

```
Party
-------------------
XYZ & A
```

Comment: 200000 lines hardly qualifies as "huge".

Comment: Regarding your update, awk is fantastic when the fields are more or less fixed, if all fields are dynamic it get tricky. Is it possible to make the file a csv-one, i.e. a comma separates the different columns or something similar. Then this problem will be very easy to solve.

Comment: i can probably use sed to replace multiple spaces with comma. That would be a seperate question, as I said am very new to shell.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I used a combination of cut and awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '($2+0) < 25{print $3}' input
Party
------------------
USR
```

**Update**

Various for-loops to determine which field that contains the number (n), then the name is in `$1..n` and the party-field is in `$n+1..NF-1`

```
/Shub A/ {
    # determine which field that contains a number
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ /[0-9]+$/) {
            break
        }
    }
    for (j=1;j<i;j++) {
        printf "%s ", $j
    }
    for (k=(i+1);k<NF;k++) {
        printf "%s ", $k
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Shub A XYZ & A
```

...or you can try to split on "2 spaces or more" i.e.

```
$ awk -F"  +" '/^Shub/{print $3}' input
XYZ & A
```

Comment: What if I want to do a select on the basis of name ? awk '($1+0) == "Shubham"{print $3}' isnt working for me ?

Comment: oh ok, gt it ! Also this isnt working if the Name has a space, for eg. if the Name is Shubh A . How do i overcome the space problem ?

Comment: Do you mean like this `awk '$1=="Shubham"{print $3}' input` if you tell awk to split on whitespace (the default) then strings are trimmed

Comment: if there are spaces in the name. Things get a little trickier. Update your question and we'll have a look! The parameter `NF` contains the number of fields. `$NF` is the last one, `$NF-1` second last one and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS = "11 11 19 14" } NR<3 || $1~/^Shub A +$/{print $3}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. It prints the first two lines (header) and after that compares if second fields is lower than 25.

```
awk 'FNR < 3 || $2 < 25 { print $3 }' infile
```

It yields:

```
Party
------------------
USR
```

---

**EDIT: This is posted before the update and doesn't work for it. Take a look to other answers**

Answer (score 0):

try this, if it works for u:

```
 awk 'NR<3||($2+0)<25{a[++i]=$3}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that none of your ages fill the full 10 digits, you can probably just do:

```
< input-file cut -b 11-30 | awk '$1 < 25' | cut -b 11-
```